# How to create nested domain in nestjs graphql?

Tags: graphql, nestjs

How to create subdomains in nestjs/graphql?

to be able to query something like

```
query {
  Foo {
   Bar {
     search(page: 1) {
       id name
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Basically how can I create the `Foo` and `Bar` handlers?